# subtract consecutive set elements

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-set

I am trying to implement a set version of the `solLoops` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

int solLoops(std::vector<int> A)
{

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i + 1] - A[i] <= 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int solSet(std::vector<int> A)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> S;

    for (int i = 0; i  < A.size(); ++i)
    {
        S.insert(A[i]);
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (auto it = S.begin(); it != std::prev(S.end()); ++it)
    {
        auto it2 = std::next(it, 1);
        if (*it2 - *it <= 1)
        {   
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}



int main() {

    const unsigned int N = 4;

    std::vector<int> A;
    A.reserve(N);
    A.emplace_back(11);
    A.emplace_back(12);
    A.emplace_back(13);
    A.emplace_back(1);
    A.emplace_back(2);

    //int result = solLoops(A);
    int result = solSet(A);
    std::cout << "Result is: " << result << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

but I am getting a seg fault.
I am trying to implement the loop:

`for (int i = 0; i < A.size() - 1; ++i)`

by

`for (auto it = S.begin(); it != std::prev(S.end()); ++it)`

and make the subtraction:

`if (A[i + 1] - A[i] <= 1)`

as

`auto it2 = std::next(it, 1);
        if (*it2 - *it <= 1)`

(I know that the set contains the elements in random order. I am just trying to figure how to do the subtraction here)

Comment: Why not just use a non-unordered std::set, which _does_ have bidirectional iterators?

Comment: An `unordered_set` has forward iterators.  Which means `std::prev(S.end())` is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) have [*forward* iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (which can only go forward). But [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) requires a [*bidirectional* iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator).

You can solve your problem by checking if the *next* iterator is the end or not: `std::next(it) != S.end()`. Or use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead, which *have* bidirectional iterators.

Comment: Ok, I missed that, thanks.I am using set now but the result is different from the simple loop version.Result is 3 with the set version and 4 with the loops.Am I missing something else?

Comment: @George You might want to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Either add plenty of "debug printing", or step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Ok, I forgot that set sorts the elements, ok now.